# How to access WC() inside a PHP callback file with jQuery and .get

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to set a `WC()->set` inside a php jquery `.get` function.  What do I need to do inside of the php file to get access to the `WC()`. Right now it is telling me that `WC` is undefined.

This is inside my `cart.php` file that displays the cart and shows two radio buttons for a delivery options.

Here is the script that handles the RB change (I've simplified just to get the function to execute the reload upon return from the php query):

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $("#myid").change(function(){            

            console.log("RB Changed!"); 
            passed_variable = "1";

            $.get('http://www.example.com/test.php',
            {pass_var: passed_variable}, 
            function(data, status) {
                console.log("returned");
                location.reload();                
                });
         });
    });
</script>
```

And here is the PHP query:

```
<?php

global $woocommerce;
echo "START<BR>";
$temp = $_GET["pass_var"];


WC()->session->set('_delivery_loading', $temp);
 // or 
$woocommerce->session->set('_delivery_loading', $temp);

 echo "DONE[" . $temp . "]";

?>
```

Comment: Are you including the file where `WC()` is declared from your PHP file called by jQuery? Also, show us what you've done so far, what you've tried, so we can better help you.

Comment: Presumably you're accessing a PHP file at a point where WooCommerce has not yet been included. If you use `.ajax` and set up a callback then WooCommerce should be loaded. See the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)).

Comment: @Howl    I updated the question to include code.  Basically this is on my check out php and the radio button sets a session variable that will then be read when the window is reloaded forcing an update in the calculation.  The "test.php" is getting called the error log is telling me MC() is not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to call `test.php`? If you use a `wp_ajax_$action` callback you will be within the WP framework and `WC()` will be loaded. here's an example cobbled together from the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) and jQuery [.ajax()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)).

Enqueue the script you will be making the ajax calls from:

```
function so_34107959_enqueue_script(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'so_34107959_script', plugins_url( '/js/so_34107959.js' , __FILE__ ), '1.0b', array('wc-add-to-cart'), true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_34107959_enqueue_script' );
```

Note that the `wc-add-to-cart` script is a dependency. I'm only doing that so we can use WooCommerce's localized script variables. If you need to use this somewhere that the add to cart script isn't used then you will need to [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) and pass in the admin ajax url yourself.

Your script file `so_34107959.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $("#myid").change(function(){    

            var passed_var = "1";        

            $.ajax({
                url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url, // here's the ajax url from WooCommerce
                data: { action: "add_foobar", pass_var: passed_var } // the action must match up to wp_ajax_$action
            })
            .done(function( data ) {
                if ( console && console.log ) {
                    // should return either success or fail
                    console.log( data );
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

And finally this code is the callback for your ajax "action":

```
function so_34107959_ajax_add_foobar() {
    $temp = isset( $_REQUEST["pass_var"] ) ? $_REQUEST["pass_var"] : '';
    if( $test ){
        WC()->session->set('_delivery_loading', $temp);
        echo 'success';
    } else {
        echo 'fail';
    }
    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_foobar', 'so_34107959_ajax_add_foobar' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_foobar', 'so_34107959_ajax_add_foobar' );
```

Untested, so watch out for typos.

**Further explanations:**

The PHP code assumes that you are writing a plugin. You could cheat and put it in your theme's `functions.php` but I think the theme should be kept for presentation and any functionality should be in plugins.

The codex has this explanation for the `wp_ajax_$action` hook:

> This hook allows you to create custom handlers for your own custom AJAX requests. The wp_ajax_ hook follows the format "wp_ajax_$youraction", where $youraction is your AJAX request's 'action' property.

This means that if you pass an "action" to the "data" in your `.ajax()` that same action will wind up as the tail end of your `wp_ajax_$youraction` callback.

In my example therefore here's the data bit from the `.ajax()` script: 
     data: { action: "add_foobar", pass_var: passed_var }

The action is "add_foobar". It can be whatever.

Then you append that action "add_foobar" to the end of "wp_ajax_" so that `add_action()` looks like:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_foobar', 'so_34107959_ajax_add_foobar' );
```

This is for the admin/logged in users. The "nopriv" in:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_foobar', 'so_34107959_ajax_add_foobar' );
```

means that the ajax hook is available to non-logged in users.

Lastly, `so_34107959_ajax_add_foobar()` is the the server-side function that will handle your ajax request.

Comment: So @helpatheviking i'm intrigued with your solution. I've never used this approach so have a few questions. Where does all of the code other than the .js go? What are the naming conventions for action: "add_foobar" that then gets "translated to" function so_34107959_ajax_add_foobar() if I'm following this right. I think this is the right path, I just need to set a WC-session-set based on the change of the Radio button and then call window.reload so the function.php reruns

Comment: Yes that is exactly the naming convention. I've tried to elaborate my answer to explain that more. You do not need to call `window.reload`, that's the beauty of the ajax request. Also, here's a [tutorial by Pippen](https://pippinsplugins.com/using-ajax-your-plugin-wordpress-admin/) on using ajax in plugins. All his tutorials are excellent.

Comment: @helpatheviking explaination.  I'm really going to try this!  One more question.  Why the prefix name "so_34107959"  is that following a standard?  And I'm going to try and understand how I don't need to call reload.window and yet get this delivery charge to show up if the RB is checked rather than the reload forcing the function.php to rerun which is where the logic is now to add the charge.

Comment: The prefix "so_34107959" just stands for "stack overflow" and the number is the question number here. It is just guarantees that you'll never get a fatal error from a function with the same name, but it doesn't have any bearing on how the code works. This doesn't get you a delivery charge as that's a separate question, but this gets the value into the session variables.